# 11 year old cat is on a diet but constantly begs for food

Tags: cats, feeding

Our vet said that our cat is getting more sedentary so we should cut her calorie intake and only feed her two half-portions of wet food twice a day (one half in morning and one half at night). She's been on this diet for nearly a year and yet every time a human so much as moves, she gets up and follows and meows for food. We haven't broken the diet at all, as we hoped she would just adjust. But she hasn't. It's worrying me because are we starving her? Maybe because she's older she can't adjust as well to a smaller diet? Should we go back to the automatic dry food feeder? The meowing is really quite incessant and I don't want her to be miserable.

Comment: do you feed your cat a type of food made  for senior cats?,this type of food do often contain less calories and more fibres so your cat will feel full for a longer period of time.

Comment: Have you tried feeding the recommended amount in smaller meals spread over the day? If you've used automatic feeders before, the cat might be used to grazing small amounts throughout the day.

Comment: Another possibility is your cat is getting too bored.  Cats might want to eat more simply because they're bored, much like humans.